# Pivot logic to be created in Java/jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting a table(shown below) in java which I am printing it in jsp page.

```
ColumnA     Column B                    Count
A           STARTS WITHIN 16 - 30 DAYS  3
B           STARTS WITHIN 1 - 15 DAYS   1
B           STARTS WITHIN 16 - 30 DAYS  2
C           STARTS WITHIN 1 - 15 DAYS   1
C           STARTS WITHIN 16 - 30 DAYS  2
```

Can anyone tell how do i convert above format in the format shown below.It can either be in jsp or java.

```
 Column A   STARTS WITHIN 1 - 15 DAYS   STARTS WITHIN 16 - 30 DAYS  Total
A                    0                                         3          3
B                    1                                         2          3
C                    1                                         2          3
```

I've tried this:

```
<div class="container" style="position: absolute; top: 34%; left: 1%;"> 
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 85%;"> 
        <thead> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Column A</th> 
                <th>STARTS WITHIN 1 - 15 DAYS</th> 
                <th>STARTS WITHIN 16 - 30 DAYS</th> 
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
        <c:forEach var="demand" items="${demands}" varStatus="status"> 
            <tr> 
                 <td>${demand.getSeatJRSS()}</td> 
                 <td> </td> 
                 <td></td> 
            </tr> 
        </c:forEach> 
        </tbody> 
    </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="container" style="position: absolute; top: 34%; left: 1%;">
  <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 85%;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column A</th>
        <th>STARTS WITHIN 1 - 15 DAYS</th>
        <th>STARTS WITHIN 16 - 30 DAYS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <c:forEach var="demand" items="${demands}" varStatus="status">
      <tr>
        <td>${demand.getSeatJRSS()}</td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td></td>    
      </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

here is your complete solution. It's in JAVA,

please review it,

```
class SampleData{

    private  String key;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> headerKeyName = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    private int total;
    private String hashMapkey;
    private Integer hashMapValue;

    SampleData(String key, String hashMapkey, Integer hashMapValue){
        this.key = key;
        this.hashMapkey = hashMapkey;
        this.hashMapValue = hashMapValue;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getHeaderKeyName() {
        return headerKeyName;
    }

    public void setHeaderKeyName(HashMap<String, Integer> headerKeyName) {
        this.headerKeyName = headerKeyName;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getHashMapkey() {
        return hashMapkey;
    }

    public void setHashMapkey(String hashMapkey) {
        this.hashMapkey = hashMapkey;
    }

    public Integer getHashMapValue() {
        return hashMapValue;
    }

    public void setHashMapValue(Integer hashMapValue) {
        this.hashMapValue = hashMapValue;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.getHashMapkey().length();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        SampleData sd = (SampleData)obj;

        if(sd.getKey().equals(this.getKey()) &&  sd.getHashMapkey().equals(this.getHashMapkey())){
            sd.setHashMapValue(sd.getHashMapValue() + this.getHashMapValue());
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

your main class is,

```
public class StackOverflowQuery{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [][]answer;

        SampleData s1 = new SampleData("A", "STARTS WITHIN 16 - 30 DAYS", 3); // set this value from your 
        SampleData s2 = new SampleData("B", "STARTS WITHIN 1 - 15 DAYS", 1);
        SampleData s3 = new SampleData("B", "STARTS WITHIN 16 - 30 DAYS", 2);
        SampleData s4 = new SampleData("C", "STARTS WITHIN 1 - 15 DAYS", 1);
        SampleData s5 = new SampleData("C", "STARTS WITHIN 16 - 30 DAYS", 2);
        SampleData s6 = new SampleData("C", "STARTS WITHIN 16 - 30 DAYS", 2);
        SampleData s7 = new SampleData("D", "STARTS WITHIN 31 - 45 DAYS", 2);

        HashSet<SampleData> hs = new LinkedHashSet<SampleData>();
        Map<String, SampleData> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, SampleData>();

        hs.add(s1);
        hs.add(s2);
        hs.add(s3);
        hs.add(s4);
        hs.add(s5);
        hs.add(s6);
        hs.add(s7);

        Set<String> listOfHeaders = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

        listOfHeaders.add("Key");

        for(SampleData sd: hs){
            listOfHeaders.add(sd.getHashMapkey());
        }

        listOfHeaders.add("total");

        for(String listofHead : listOfHeaders){
            System.out.print(listofHead + "\t");
        }

        System.out.println();
        for(SampleData sd: hs){
            if(hashMap.get(sd.getKey()) != null){
                SampleData sampleData = hashMap.get(sd.getKey());

                HashMap<String , Integer> hm = sampleData.getHeaderKeyName();

                if(hm.get(sd.getHashMapkey()) != null){
                    hm.put(sd.getHashMapkey(), hm.get(sd.getHashMapkey()) + sd.getHashMapValue());
                }else{
                    hm.put(sd.getHashMapkey(), sd.getHashMapValue());
                }
                sampleData.setTotal(sampleData.getTotal() + sd.getHashMapValue().intValue());

                hashMap.put(sd.getKey(), sampleData);
            }else{
                sd.getHeaderKeyName().put(sd.getHashMapkey(), sd.getHashMapValue());
                sd.setTotal( sd.getHashMapValue().intValue());
                sd.getHeaderKeyName().put(sd.getHashMapkey(), sd.getHashMapValue());
                hashMap.put(sd.getKey(), sd);
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        for(Entry<String, SampleData>  entry : hashMap.entrySet()){

            int tempArrayIndex = 0;
            System.out.print(entry.getKey() + " \t\t ");
            SampleData currentSampleData = entry.getValue();
            for(String listofHead : listOfHeaders){
                if(listofHead.equalsIgnoreCase("Key") || listofHead.equalsIgnoreCase("total") ){
                    continue; // it's not part of print over here..
                }
                if(currentSampleData.getHeaderKeyName().get(listofHead) != null){
                    System.out.print(currentSampleData.getHeaderKeyName().get(listofHead)  + " \t\t ");
                }else{
                    System.out.print(" 0 \t\t ");
                }

            }
            System.out.print(currentSampleData.getTotal());
            System.out.println();

        }

    }

}
```

And **out-put**(I am sorry to don't provide out-put in a proper formate) will be,

```
Key STARTS WITHIN 16 - 30 DAYS  STARTS WITHIN 1 - 15 DAYS   STARTS WITHIN 31 - 45 DAYS  total   

A        3       0        0          3
B        2       1        0          3
C        4       1        0          5
D        0       0        2          2
```